# How to set up gist to work with an existing token?

Tags: ruby, github, gist

I've installed gist Ruby gem. However, I'm having trouble setting up my gist to work with an existing GitHub account and taken. I've read the instructions in [here](http://defunkt.io/gist/#EXAMPLES). However, I'm lost on the next steps I should try to get the authentication working despite following the instructions.

### Update

Found [this issue to be open](https://github.com/defunkt/gist/issues) in its GitHub page.

Not much I can do at this point.

Answer (score 0):

You should use your github password, not token: https://github.com/defunkt/gist#authentication